# Installing gfortran and mpich for a new Ubuntu user

Tags: mac, cpu, fortran, mpi

I am a long-term Mac user who is considering switching to Ubuntu.    I am not a system guru.    I program in fortran and mpi for cfd applications on high-performance computers.

I am considering getting 32 cores using 2 x
Intel Xeon E5-2683 V4 processors for software development.     Installing gfortran (gcc-5.2)  and mpich-3.2 on a Mac is reasonably straight forward for someone with my background, but I am concerned that I will have trouble installing gfortran and mpi using Ubuntu linux.

The system that I am considering buying is a lot more powerful and cheaper than a 12-core Mac Pro, but it only makes sense if I can get fortran and mpi working on it.   How big of a job is it for someone with very limited Ubuntu experience aside from testing it using a CD on my Mac, which went well?

Answer (score 1):

If you install Ubuntu 16.04, it should be this simple to install mpich3.2 and gfortran 4.5 with GCC 5.3:

Open a terminal

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install gfortran mpich gcc-5
```

Comment: If I also want to use OpenMP in combination with MPI and Fortran, what alternatives are available to me?   I want MPI to be my default for communication across the processors, but for inner loops, I would like to use OpenMP.

Comment: @DougDommermuth I can't answer that, unfortunately. I don't think the question will get much attention here in the comments either, so perhaps you should edit the original question to include that, or ask it as a new question.

Comment: @Tobias, how can we set default mpicc e.g. CC variable not set, CC = /usr/bin/mpicc

Comment: @ABCDEMMM Unfortuantely I don't know anything about MPIC or GFORTRAN, I just checked which packages contained what was needed. I'm not sure what exactly you're asking, but if you want to make the environment variable CC equal to /usr/bin/mpicc - you can add it to /etc/environments - or you can edit it on the fly with CC = /usr/bin/mpicc.

Comment: @Tobias, do you mean in file .bash file I should add "CC=/usr/bin/mpicc"?

Comment: No, I mean if you want to run the command foo, then instead of typing 'foo', you type 'CC=/usr/bin/mpicc foo' - you prepepend the variable assignment. If you want to 'permanently' change it, add the line to /etc/environment.